# plot with time data from 11pm to 9am, goes back

Tags: time, gnuplot

I have a file that looks like this:

```
fmp@lila asc-47$ head -n 2 imp
23:22:37  23.3769   240.800   581.300     1.000     1.000    -2.839    -0.360     5.114     2.076 
23:23:07  23.3853   240.700   580.300     1.000     1.000    -2.838    -0.358     5.114     2.079 
fmp@lila asc-47$ tail -n 2 imp
09:22:23   9.3731   257.300   636.900     1.000     1.000    -2.867    -0.358     5.103     2.082 
09:22:53   9.3814   257.200   635.800     1.000     1.000    -2.867    -0.358     5.104     2.082
```

I want to plot column 3 vs column 1.

My gnuplot file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/gnuplot
#
set terminal svg size 1400,1048 enhanced fname 'Verdana' fsize 12 
set output 'curr-imp.svg'
unset key
set xlabel 'Tiempo (h)'
set ylabel 'Corriente (mA)'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H"
set style line 1 lc rgb '#000000' pt 6 ps 1 lt 1 lw 2 # --- black with empty circles
set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
set border 3 back ls 11
set tics nomirror
set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set grid back ls 12
plot 'imp' u 1:3  ls 1 w lp
```

Which gives me almost the desired output.
[image: current vs time]

The problem is that the line goes back, because the time goes from about 23pm to 09am. I was thinking that maybe I should have the date along with the time. Or there is  another way to solve this? Lots of thanks for your time

Comment: Please see [python gnuplot read csv file to plot time in x-axis in the read order or row order](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25308739/2604213) for an identical question. I'm voting for duplicate. My suggestion would be though, if you have control over your data output, write a timestamp :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of clarity I will show how I did things at the end. (The link provided is not exactly my case, because I have the data for the different days in different files.)
First, add the date1 to file1 and date2 to file2 with vim (`:%s/^/27-06-14/g` or `:%s/^/28-06-14/g` In México we write day-month-year).

```
fmp@lila asc-47$ head -n 1 imp-27
27-06-14    23:22:37  23.3769   240.800   581.300     1.000     1.000    -2.839  -0.360     5.114     2.076 
fmp@lila asc-47$ tail -n 1 imp-28
28-06-14    09:22:53   9.3814   257.200   635.800     1.000     1.000    -2.867    -0.358     5.104     2.082
```

Then, merge the file1 and file2 with cat.
After that, just change the lines:

`set timefmt "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%H %p"
....
plot 'imp' u 1:4  ls 1 w lp`

and you are done. :)
[image]

Comment: Well, as you wrote your question it is an exact duplicate, you haven't mentioned that you have one data file for each day. With gnuplot you could also add this information on-the-fly as `plot '< awk "..." imp'`